# Why is git misinterpreting a colon in my submodule URL?

Tags: git, azure-web-app-service, git-submodules, kudu

My repo's `.gitmodules` file looks like this:

```
[submodule "deps/Framework"]
    path = deps/Framework
    url = git://git@github.com/MyOrg/framework-php.git
    branch = reorg
[submodule "deps/MyClient"]
    path = deps/MyClient
    url = git://git@github.com/MyOrg/myclient-php.git
    branch = publish
```

when I run `git submodule update --init --progress` in Azure Kudu's command-line I get this error:

```
Cloning into 'D:/home/site/repository/mywebsite/deps/MyClient'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:MyOrg: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'ssh://git@github.com:My/Myclient-php.git' into submodule path 'D:/home/site/repository/mywebsite/deps/MyClient' failed
Failed to clone 'deps/MyClient'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'D:/home/site/repository/mywebsite/deps/Framework'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:MyOrg: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Why is it converting `github.com/MyOrg` into `github.com:MyOrg` (which is a valid SSH URL anyway) and then rejecting it?

My `git config -l` output does not list any `submodule...` entries.

Comment: Do you have any URL substitutions defined (using `insteadOf`)?